# can I make a ruby GUI in javascript/html/css?

Tags: javascript, ruby

**this is not a ruby on rails question**

I just finished up a ruby basics course on teamtreehouse and I'm sitting
here thinking of what I want to make to demonstrate to myself that I
grasped what I learned.

I have a plan to write a program to automate setting up new hire files
and folders on a network directory at my work at the click of a button.
It might be nice to have a GUI for it instead of running it through the
command line.

First off, is this possible to run ruby with javascript and html without
running it through a server?

I'm trying to think of different ways I would get ruby to speak with
javascript. My first thought was to use a JSON file to produce url links
from in my webpage, but I have no idea how I would run the ruby program
from the web page.

probably a dumb question. Im trying to come up with a good project to
get some confidence in bare bones ruby before I pursue ruby on rails or
sinatra.

Comment: I learned ruby CGI a while back.  Similar to php webpages.  I used Apache webserver, and I think there is even mod_ruby which is like mod_perl.  Please google any of these terms for more info.

Comment: The previous was on Windows OS, I think there are better ruby servers for Linux OS.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to run Ruby and many other languages in the browser would be to use a Ruby to JS compiler like http://opalrb.org/. Here's a huge list of more languages then you can shake a stick at: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/list-of-languages-that-compile-to-js#ruby.

The only trick is to make sure that the *compiler* can also be run in the browser not just the code it produces.

Hopefully that helps.

---- edit ----

I think I perhaps didn't read your question as much as I should have. As for comunication between the server and the client goes, I would say go with [sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html). It's really very simple, and you don't even have to use a database if it's just a project to learn with. Just modify files and save your data that way.

If you want a more dynamic front end making AJAX calls then you can just make a *route* in sinatra that would return back the information in an easy to parse form for JS such as JSON.

Comment: This might work if I can compile a Ruby file and run it to produce a JSON file. Then I can just query the JSON file to get the results with Ajax, I will give it a go and then mark this as the answer later on!

Comment: Haha, just edited my answer (before I saw your comment) to kind of reflect that. Good luck :).